# Go xml.Unmarshal get only last item of list

Tags: go, xml-parsing

there!

I'm parsing xml document and unmarshal it's contents to the struct, but it returns only last item from the list instead of full list.

The list is `serverList` and after unmarshalling it returns only last `server` instance. Need help.

```
func main() {
    xmlFile := `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <operationGetServerList>
      <returnCode>0</returnCode>
      <message></message>
      <serverList>
      <server>
          <serverId>1</serverId>
          <nauServer>Main</nauServer>
          <serverIp>1.1.1.1</serverIp>
          <serverPort>8080</serverPort>
          <serverPortFtp>25</serverPortFtp>
          <serverHome>true</serverHome>
          <serverIsOnline>true</serverIsOnline>
        </server>
        <server>
          <serverId>2</serverId>
          <nauServer>Reg1</nauServer>
          <serverIp>1.1.1.2</serverIp>
          <serverPort>8080</serverPort>
          <serverPortFtp>25</serverPortFtp>
          <serverHome>false</serverHome>
          <serverIsOnline>false</serverIsOnline>
        </server>
      </serverList>
    </operationGetServerList>`

    type serverInfo struct {
        ServerID       string `xml:"serverId"`
        NauServer      string `xml:"nauServer"`
        ServerIP       string `xml:"serverIp"`
        ServerPort     int    `xml:"serverPort"`
        ServerPortFtp  int    `xml:"serverPortFtp"`
        ServerHome     bool   `xml:"serverHome"`
        ServerIsOnline bool   `xml:"serverIsOnline"`
    }

    type serverInstance struct {
        Server serverInfo `xml:"server"`
    }

    type operationGetServerListResponce struct {
        ReturnCode int              `xml:"returnCode"`
        Message    string           `xml:"message"`
        ServerList []serverInstance `xml:"serverList"`
    }

    var sL operationGetServerListResponce
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlFile), &sL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", sL)

}
```

Prints:

```
{ReturnCode:0 Message: ServerList:[{Server:{ServerID:4 NauServer:Res2 ServerIP:1.1.1.4 ServerPort:8080 ServerPortFtp:25 ServerHome:false ServerIsOnline:true}}]}
```

Comment: ... And you actually don't need the `serverInstance` type inbetween (https://play.golang.org/p/roGyLMocTwJ) This: `ServerList []serverInfo \`xml:"serverList>server"\`` is enough.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you for your help, but first example returns list with null values. Second one is ok.

Comment: You're right, my bad, deleting it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML does not have a list of `ServerList`, instead `ServerList` contains a list of `Server`.

You need to change your structs to the following:

```
type serverInstance struct {
    Server []serverInfo `xml:"server"`
}

type operationGetServerListResponce struct {
    ReturnCode int              `xml:"returnCode"`
    Message    string           `xml:"message"`
    ServerList serverInstance   `xml:"serverList"`
}
```

This will properly output all servers:

```
 {ReturnCode:0 Message: ServerList:{Server:[{ServerID:1 NauServer:Main
 ServerIP:1.1.1.1 ServerPort:8080 ServerPortFtp:25 ServerHome:true
 ServerIsOnline:true} {ServerID:2 NauServer:Reg1 ServerIP:1.1.1.2
 ServerPort:8080 ServerPortFtp:25 ServerHome:false
 ServerIsOnline:false} {ServerID:3 NauServer:Res1 ServerIP:1.1.1.3
 ServerPort:8080 ServerPortFtp:25 ServerHome:false
 ServerIsOnline:false} {ServerID:4 NauServer:Res2 ServerIP:1.1.1.4
 ServerPort:8080 ServerPortFtp:25 ServerHome:false
 ServerIsOnline:true}]}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've misunderstands xml arrays. That is the right answer.